# Javascript two async methods at once

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to simulate two asynchronous methods but am failing to figure out the concept behind it. I have this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3tqFu2UVZbVFqTvJKoS3?p=preview) where I am trying to calculate fibonacci number and at the same time do some additional work. The code required for the issue is located in `src/app.ts` The actions are as follows:

1. I click **Get Fibonacci**
2. Immediately after I click **Click while Fibonacci loads** a few times

I want the result to be like

`loading status status status finished`

but I get

`loading finished status status status`

because my promise locks UI and I am failing to understand how to make it not do so. If not looking at the example, the code for the promise looks like this:

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  resolve(this.fibonacci(num));
);
promise.then(result => {
  this.result = result;
  this.status += " finished";
});
```

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Where can I find your js file in that plunker?

Comment: @moon src/app.ts - also added this in the question

Comment: You should do this calculation in separate thread with web workers.

Comment: @dfsq I assumed keyword `async` is enough to make multithreading. My bad :(

Comment: I think the fibonacci function use too much recursive calls, try to use a non-recursive version

Comment: @Quentin it's not really a duplicate since it doesn't solve OP problem, however it explains promises. Webworker question would be more helpful I think.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius Here is an example of the approach that will work better for you using web workers: https://plnkr.co/edit/BXRtjQSvcrpVj57bwoq2?p=preview

Comment: `"I assumed keyword async is enough ..."` a common misconseption about JS and thinking that `await` pauses your code. Your code runs in one thread and one thread only so your code should not block. But when you call the `fetch` api (making http request) then how do you deal with the delay of return? This is why the `fetch` api and other native api's return a promise or use callback. It'll natively make the http request on another thread but immediately returns a promise to your script that you then can immediately return (non blocking).

Comment: @dfsq I suggest you put your comment as a separate answer as it does the job perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: I would post it if the question was not closed as duplicate :) But nevermind, you are welcome!